# solving an ODE: problem with integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the ODE
\begin{align*}
 - \left(|u'|^{p-2}u'\right)' & = 1 \quad \mathrm{in}\ (-a,a)\\
u(\pm a) & = 0
\end{align*}
for $1<p<\infty$ and $a>0$.

I thought I could do this by integration, but the first integration lead me to
$$-|u'|^{p-2}u' = x+c$$ for some constant $c$.

To obtain $u$ I tried integrating this again, but I cannot solve the integral,
$$\int_{-a}^a |u'|^{p-2}u' d x$$ 
I already tried integration by parts, but I don't know how to handle the absolute value of the derivative of $u$.

Does anyone have an idea or know another way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-|u'|^{p-2}u' = x+c$$
Consider separately the cases $u'$ positive or negative. For example in the positive case :
$$-u'^{p-2}u' =-u'^{p-1} = x+c$$
If $p\neq 1$ :
$$u'=(-x-c)^{1/(p-1)}$$
and if $p\neq 0$ :
$$u=\int (x+c)^{1/(p-1)}dx = \frac{p-1}{p}(-x-c)^{p/(p-1)} +C$$
Compute $c$ and $C$ according to the conditions $u(\pm a)=0$. Compute $u'$ and see if it satisfies the hypothesis $u'$ positive. 
Solve separately the particular cases $p=0$, $p=1$. Similarly, study the cases corresponding to $u'$ negative.

Comment: okay, I tried your approach, but I always get a contradition. For $u'\geq 0$ I obtain $u(x) = \frac{1}{q}(c-x)^q$ for $q=p/(p-1)$. This leads me to $u(a)=\frac{1}{q}(c-a)^q +C$, $u(-a)=\frac{1}{q}(c+a)^q+C$ and consequently $c-a=c+a$, which holds for ever $c$ but only $a=0$. I'm running into the same thing for $u'<0$. Hence the ODE cannot have a solution but I don't think this is true. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The function $u(x)$ that you are trying to use is not convenient for all $x$ because on some range it is not real. Hint : $u(x)$ must be a piecewise function. This will lead you to $c=0$ and consider two functions one for $x>0$ and the other for $x<0$. Then, combine them on the form : $u(x)=-\frac{1}{q}|x|^q + \frac{a^q}{q}$